# Main thread tries to access data not yet populated by Background thread

Tags: c#, background-process

I have a UI which takes 10-15 seconds to load. So implemented Background thread (BG Thread) to load data.
As BG Thread gets data, main thread starts to execute remainder of the code and this is where problem starts..i.e.

When step 1 below, is executed by BG Thread only... main thread tries to execute step 2

How do I make sure that until I get records from background thread (Step 1), step 2 is not executed?

So, here are the steps that gets executes..

```
===========This piece is executed only by BG Thread===============================================
Step 1. Get data from DB
   new Thread(() => 
   {
    Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true; 
    My DB call goes here... and populates productCollection used in step 2 below
   }).Start();

==========================================================

Step 2.
if(productCollection?.Count > 0)  // This collection is always 0 becuase BG Thread (step 1) has not yet populated the collection and user get "No record message"
{

  // Filter collection based on some criteria
  // assign the filtered collection to datagrid
  dgProducts.DataSource = productCollection;      
}
else
{
 // show message to user that "No records found for given criteria";
}
```

Comment: Why not use `async`/`await`?

Comment: In case of async /await, same amount of time is taken to load data, there is no change. I had tried async/await using below example earlier. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/async-and-await-in-c-sharp/

Comment: That's the whole point of async/await. You're going to end up waiting the same amount of time (_especially_ if it currently takes 15 seconds!) unless you can make multiple calls at once, but using async means the compiler manages it for you. So you don't have to worry about forcibly creating new threads. But the real value is knowing when the data is finished loading, like your question asks; `await` does that for you.

Comment: This seems like a good place to use a background worker then you can just use the completed event to run step two and it will not lock up your UI.

Comment: Agreed. However, my issue of loading data quickly remains same i.e. taking  10-15 seconds... :(  BG thread did help and loaded data in 3 seconds, but ran into other issue mentioned in my query.

Comment: Well you could have it process some of the data in a background worker by implementing UpdateProgress (for instance after you add a row that could be displayed) then the datagrid will update everytime there is a new piece of data to show.

Comment: @Carter - Is there any example in your knowledge I can take a look at ?

Comment: You can add a block using WaitOne().  See msdn : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx, or this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You seem to think that threads will magically make methods faster, this is not the case at all.

Comment: Yea it is a question of if your query to your database is just slow, if that is the case time to rev up the DB Profiler and add some indexes to make it faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it like this with a task.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SetDataSource();
    }

    public async void SetDataSource()
    {
        dgProducts.DataSource = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //My DB call goes here... and populates productCollection used in step 2 below
            return productCollection;
        });
    }
}
```

On the other hand if you were wrong and the query just really takes 10-15 seconds this will not help you.  Then you should be looking into how to speed up your DB Calls inside of your DB.